# How to have VirtualBox with XP - Accessing Ubuntu localhost?

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualbox

On my Ubuntu hosts file I have something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 something.dev
```

So when I type `http://something.dev` I got the desired result.

I wish to do the same, but by using the browser located on the virtualbox.

If I do: `10.0.2.2` I get my ubuntu localhost.

But I wish to access *something.dev* specifically.

How can we do such a thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `10.0.2.2 something.dev` to the hosts file of your host OS (WinXP)

Comment: Thanks. That will not work I believe. If I do that, I will get my localhost root page when I do something.dev. But I must somehow, point it to my uuntu local path (where that specific site files are located) and NOT, to localhost root. (Hope this is clear).

Comment: Change 10.0.2.2 to the IP address for the Ubuntu Virtual Machine.